# Get the Google Meet mute mic keyboard shortcut working in Safari 14?

Tags: safari, macos

I've had to switch from Chrome to Safari to get my external web cam to transmit in 720p quality. In the process, I've lost an essential keyboard shortcut in Google Meet: Cmd-D -- it mutes the microphone in Meet when running in Chrome or Firefox.

Unfortunately, Cmd-D is mapped to `Bookmarks > Add Bookmark...` in Safari.

I don't see a way to un-map Cmd-D in Safari so the key pair press gets passed to the application running in the browser. Is this even possible in Safari? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to un-assigning shortcuts in any app on the Mac is to assign the shortcut you want to use you first have to assign that shortcut keystroke to something else.

1. `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`
2. Click the + and select Safari.app from the Application menu
3. Now type in the menu title **EXACTLY** as it appears in the menu. noting that the three dots after the "Add Bookmark" is an elipsis and not three periods, so type <kbd>Opt</kbd> <kbd>;</kbd>  to get that symbol.
4. Now give the shortcut a new key sequence, like <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and click Add.
5. Once that is done I would go back to Safari and verify that this shortcut works. It will show up in the Bookmarks menu correctly if you did it right.
6. Now you can either assign your desired shortcut to <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Or, in your case, leave it unassigned so it is passed to the browser window.

This will work with *any* app that you want to not use a particular keyboard shortcut and change it to your preferred shortcut. There are programs that can do this for you, but for simple, occasional, changes like this the macOS built-in method works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remove the unwanted command by replacing it with 'garbage' - something you don't already use or need...

- System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts
- Click **+** then add the name of your desired app.
- Type the *exact* name of the menu item you wish to replace<sup>[1]</sup>
- Add a garbage command [anything will do, so long as it's not going to conflict anywhere else]

[image]

<sup>[1]</sup> This is especially important if the menu ends in an ellipsis … which typographically is not the same as three full stops ...

There is no need to specify any menu/sub-menu structure, no matter how far down the hierarchy your menu item may be - it will always find it using just the actual item name.
If you have two menu items with the same name but in different sub-menus, you can differentiate by giving the actual menu path using -> as the sub-menu indicator, eg
`File->Open->Open Special Name`